# UNION ALL not returning correct results

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

For the last decade I would have said I knew how UNION ALL worked .... until 24hrs ago!

I've got a fairly complex CTE in dbt with a UNION ALL at the end that gives the wrong results, it roughly boils down to ...

this query only returns actual_transaction records (20 records)

```
-- 20 records

select account_type 

  from actual_transactions

  where account_name = 'Accounting Fees'

union all

-- 12 records

select "Section"

  from budget_summary_report

  where account_name = 'Accounting Fees'

;
```

BUT this query returns all 32 records

```
-- 20 records

select account_type 

  from actual_transactions

  where account_name = 'Accounting Fees'

union all

-- 12 records

select "Section" abc

  from budget_summary_report

  where account_name = 'Accounting Fees'

;
```

the ONLY difference is the column alias in the budget query.

If I remove the alias, the union all doesn't work properly..

If I add the alias, the union all works perfectly.

And even CRAZIER - the abc alias was just me being silly and if I use anything else it doesn't work either.

WHY?

Comment: do you have any existing column name or any column you aliasing in select called `abc` ? Sometime SNF aliasing acts funny. If not, its crazy for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed by Snowflake Support last night - budget_summary_report is a view that is several FLATTENs of a JSON cell in a table.

When budget_summary_report is queried normally, it produces the correct results.  When it's queried as part of a UNION, it does not produce the correct results.

Solution (for me) : materialise the view as a table and then everything works as expected.